# Android implementing facebook Rebound on recyclerview items

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to implementing facebook `Rebound` on `RecyclerView` items, but after that in my solution, last item of that has animation, not all items, in fact one of `RecyclerView` items work after touch on every items

**Extended SimpleSpringListener :**

```
public class ExampleSpringListener extends SimpleSpringListener {
    private View sView;

    public void setsView(View v) {
        this.sView = v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSpringUpdate(Spring spring) {
        float mappedValue = (float) SpringUtil.mapValueFromRangeToRange(spring.getCurrentValue(), 0, 1, 1, 0.5);
        sView.setScaleX(mappedValue);
        sView.setScaleY(mappedValue);
    }
}
```

**My Adapter:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MarketListsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    mSpringListener.setsView(holder.market_lists_root);
    holder.market_lists_root.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // When pressed start solving the spring to 1.
                    mScaleSpring.setEndValue(1);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    // When released start solving the spring to 0.
                    mScaleSpring.setEndValue(0);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```